# Group By in a Table format

Tags: sql-server-2005, group-by, pivot

I am running a select statement like below to extract the report for Item Wise Sales for a particular period

```
SELECT prod_description as Product,
    sum(prod_amount) as Total_sales,
    date 
from cash_bill  
group by date,prod_description
```

I am getting the output as below in a vertical format:

```
ITEM Name                       Sales           Date
Apple                            35             12-12-2012
Orange                           10             12-12-2012
Apple                            20             13-12-2012
Orange                           12             13-12-2012
banana                           10             13-12-2012
Apple                            50             14-12-2012
Orange                           40             14-12-2012
banana                           20             14-12-2012
```

But I want the output like below in a tabular format like:

```
Item Name          12-12-2012       13-12-2012        14-12-2012
Apple                 35               20                  50
Orange                10               12                  40
banana                 0               10                  20
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Also, do you absolutely need the results formatted by SQL Server, or can you do this on the front end? (In a reporting solution perhaps)

Comment: @lc. there is no need to upgrade sql server. SQL Server 2005 has the `pivot` function that can be used to be the result

Comment: @bluefeet You're right. For some reason I thought it was added in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

This type of data transformation is a [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Starting in SQL Server 2005 there is a function that can perform this type of data rotation for you.

If you know the date values ahead of time, then you can hard-code the values:

```
select product,
  isnull([12-12-2012], 0) [12-12-2012], 
  isnull([12-13-2012], 0) [12-13-2012], 
  isnull([12-14-2012], 0) [12-14-2012]
from
(
  select 
    prod_description as Product,
    prod_amount,
    convert(char(10), date, 110) date
  from cash_bill  
) src
pivot
(
  sum(prod_amount)
  for date in ([12-12-2012], [12-13-2012], [12-14-2012])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eae5/5)

If the dates are unknown prior to run-time or you want the result to be flexible, then you can use dynamic SQL to pivot the data. The dynamic version gets the list of dates that you want as columns and then creates a sql string with those values so you can pivot:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(char(10), date, 110)) 
                    from cash_bill
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(convert(char(10), date, 110))+', 0) as '+QUOTENAME(convert(char(10), date, 110))
                    from cash_bill
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT product,' + @colsNull + ' from 
             (
                select 
                  prod_description as Product,
                  prod_amount,
                  convert(char(10), date, 110) date
                from cash_bill  
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(prod_amount)
                for date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eae5/6).

Both give the result:

```
| PRODUCT | 12-12-2012 | 12-13-2012 | 12-14-2012 |
--------------------------------------------------
|   Apple |         35 |         20 |         50 |
|  banana |          0 |         10 |         20 |
|  Orange |         10 |         12 |         40 |
```